# How to clear docs.deleted from cat-indices page of elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-5

There are a few document IDs that were rejected by elasticsearch and were added on the docs.deleted section of es.
I have fixed the issue with those document IDs.
My logstash is still reading the data and in es, instead of increasing doc count it is increasing the docs.deleted count.
I used Curl to check those doc ID and output says {"found":false}.

I need to read those document IDs.
Is there any way where i can clear the docs.deleted section?

Given below is a snapshot of my es cat-index:

```
yellow open posdata                         74WTmacrRKeyBXMHuiUxgw 5 1 2172567 122443   3.6gb   3.6gb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this using force merge

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-forcemerge.html

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/indexname/_forcemerge?max_num_segments=1'
```

Edit:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_forcemerge?only_expunge_deletes=true'
```

Comment: You might want to update that to `curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_forcemerge?only_expunge_deletes=true'` which apparently does what you want and only that.